# Focus a particular date in Material UI DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to highlight initial date to tomorrow or to a particular date in React Material UI's `DatePicker` component?

**Excerpt from my code**

```
<DatePicker
  name="dueDate"
  label="Due Date"
  disablePast
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `initialFocusedDate` prop of [DatePicker](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/DatePicker)

Below code will set the initial focussed date to tomorrow.

```
import moment from 'moment'

... 

<DatePicker
  name="dueDate"
  label="Due Date"
  initialFocusedDate={moment().add(1, 'days')}
  disablePast
/>
```

You can set the `initialFocusedDate` to which ever date you want and that gets focussed when you open the `DatePicker`.

Answer (score 0):

For MUI v5 the prop `defaultCalendarMonth` will work in case if someone want to move the selected date to previous month or year or 10 years earlier

```
<DatePicker
  name="dueDate"
  label="Due Date"
  defaultCalendarMonth={DateTime.now().minus({ years: 10 })}
  disablePast
/>
```